# Antimalware Service Executable slow down IO operations

Tags: java, io, hard-drive, antimalware

I have a java program that write some temporary files in the temp directory. The temp directory is on a SSD. The write operation is normally very fast. But now with some specific sample data it is very, very slow and the CPU of the Antimalware Service Executable is high (30% - 35%). The write speed is approx. 50 KB/s.

If I set a breakpoint on the write loop the CPU of the Antimalware go to 0%. If I continue then the CPU of the Antimalware go to high. I can repeat this multiple time.

It look like the Antimalware is scanning my temporary data intensively. Why occur this and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

To prevent scanning you can exclude files from being scanned by file name, directory name, file extension of the associated process. To do so, open “Windows Security Essential” or “Windows defender” (type it in the Start Menu).
Then go to Settings -> Excluded files and locations.

Comment: I just debugged this issue and ended up here when checking if others did the same. Talking Windows 10 Creators Update. Go to Windows Defender Security Center -> Virus & thread protection settings -> Exclusions. Here I added 'Process' 'java.exe' and everything seems fine now.